# DRF CurrentUserDefault in serializer.update with PATCH request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given the serializer below a `PATCH` request with `{'description': 'product_3'}` doesn't include `user` in the validated data.

How could you add `CurrentUserDefault()` to the validated data without calling `.save(updated_by=request.user)`?

```
class MySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'description')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['created_by'] = validated_data.pop('user')
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data['updated_by'] = validated_data.pop('user')
        return super().create(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: I think there is a security issue in your code cause I think you get current user from request (user can simply change form and submit data as other users) note that current user is already in `self.context['request'].user` you don't need to get it from user submitted data

Comment: I just tested it, even if the user submits a request with `user` included in the data it's ignored and the object is saved with the true current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CurrentUserDefault()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/90ed2c1ef7c652ce0a98075c422d25a632d62507/rest_framework/fields.py#L283)

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    user = validated_data.pop('user', None)
    validated_data['updated_by'] = user if user else self.context['request'].user
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: You can also hit this problem using nested serializers, when creating new sub-records when PATCHing the main record. The above solution works, or if you use your child serializer directly as well, you can add similar code to the `update` of the parent serializer.